# Docker does not mount volume as current user

Tags: docker

I have a website that I'm trying to run inside Docker container. To avoid file permission errors, I change the ID of user `www-data` to match my user id on host. This setup worked for me, but after some time it stopped working, and I cannot find reason why.

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

ARG HOST_UID

# Not relevant lines skipped

RUN usermod -u $HOST_UID www-data
RUN groupmod -g $HOST_UID www-data
```

Then I build container with:

`docker compose build --build-arg HOST_UID=$(id -u)`

All files on host belong to my user:

[image]

After starting container, I can see that ID is changed:

[image]

However, inside container they belong to root:

[image]

Could this be because docker daemon runs as root and mounts the volume as such?

I should have noted that this Dockerfile installs Supervisord (to run my background scripts), so I cannot run whole container with my user – this fixes permissions but nothing can be installed inside container.

Comment: The mounted volume will have whatever (numeric) ownership and permissions the corresponding host directory has.  Nothing you do in the Dockerfile will affect this; it's all hidden by the mount.  (Building a specific host user ID into a Dockerfile usually isn't a best practice, you shouldn't have to rebuild the image for different hosts or users.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, but directory on my host which I'm trying to mount, already belongs to my user. I even tried to recreate the folder under GUI before running the container. And terminal shows deniss:staff as owner

Comment: "The mounted volume will have whatever (numeric) ownership and permissions the corresponding host directory has" - I don't think this is true. Are you sure?

Comment: @DenissKozlovs running background services inside the container goes against docker's good practices. Are you sure you cannot change that?

Comment: @DenissKozlovs I actually found a way to do it, but don't know if that works for you. You need to use an actual docker volume for it. Declare the volume in docker-compose.yml, create a service that only mounts that volume and your host folder, copy files between the 2 and change ownership. It only does this and exits. Then your original php service can mount the volume directly (not your host volume) and the files will be good.

Comment: @Mihai I have a background script which works on top of legacy PHP app which I want to put inside container, so no, it is not possible to isolate it. Regarding the second volume which does only file copying, seems weird. Isn't there really a way to define ownership of the volume? Like in /etc/fstab you can define which user mounts it.

Comment: No there isn’t. Again, you are not using docker as it is intended. I guess sometimes weird problems call for weird solutions… good luck

Comment: @Mihai I'm sorry, one more question. To be more in line with Docker intentions, I have a nginx image, and php-fpm image, each does only one thing. I mount volume which is used by both nginx and php-fpm, where uploads from the website can be stored. Now php-fpm cannot write to this volume, because it belongs to root as php-fpm runs under www-data. Isn't it a valid use case?

Comment: It looks to me that this is not what you describe in your problem. If all you need is a common volume to share uploads then why are you trying to mount a volume from host which already has files in it? Also you mention background scripts and supervisord which break the containers purpose of 1 process per container. So yes what you describe above could be a valid scenario, but it’s not in line with the question. However I might be the weird one here, right? ;)

Comment: @Mihai no one is weird, I just described another scenario which I had but it shows exactly the same problem. I mount the volume from host so that these files can survive restart of the containers. The same as mounting mysql data on host so you can keep the database after restart. But in my case, web application cannot store anything on the mounted volume because it belongs to root, but php-fpm internally works as www-data. I dont want to make nginx or fpm run as root, so I cannot understand how can I mount a volume so that fpm can write to it.

Comment: The solution I describe works exactly for this. Start the container/service with that user and you can do what you want in the volume. Your limitation was othe processes in the container. Now you say that is not the issue in this new scenario. So why is my solution not working here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `-u` flag for `docker compose run`.

Here an example:

setup:

```
mkdir mihai
touch mihai/test.txt
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  test:
    image: "alpine:latest"
    volumes:
      - "./mihai:/mihai"
```

Run normal

```
docker compose run test ls -l /mihai
```

gives output:

```
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Sep 18 11:39 test.txt
```

Run as user:

```
docker compose run -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" test ls -l /mihai
```

gives output:

```
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 501      dialout          0 Sep 18 11:39 test.txt
```

If you  use a custom image where you actually declare user and group then you will see a nicer output than `501` and `dialout`.

Comment: Normally I'd expect to start the full stack of Compose services with `docker-compose up`; how does this answer work with that?  (`docker-compose run` doesn't publish `ports:`, for example.)

Comment: the question was "Could this be because docker daemon runs as root and mounts the volume as such?" and my answer proves that point. Also the question mentions "start container".  I guess it's up to the user to decide if this helps or not. I hope it does